# Date is missing from x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, nvd3.js

I am implementing graph using nvd3.js.
My code is like:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
     charts = nv.models.lineChart();
     var chart = charts.margin({
        top: 100,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 45
     }).showLegend(true).tooltipContent(function (key, y, e, graph) {
         return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' + '<p>' + e + '% at ' + y + '</p>'
     });
     chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
         return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
     });
     chart.yAxis
     .tickFormat(d3.format(',d'));

    chart.forceY([0,20]);

    d3.select('#lineChart svg')
     .datum(dateArr)
     .transition(500).duration(500)
     .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
     return chart;
 });
```

Where `dateArr` is `[{"key":"182398","values":[{"x":"1375295400000","y":"2"},{"x":"1374517800000","y":"2"},{"x":"1374604200000","y":"12"},{"x":"1374431400000", "y":"1"},{"x":"1375122600000","y":"4"},{"x":"1375209000000","y":"19"}]},{"key":"185271","values":[{"x":"1375295400000","y":"0"},{                        "x":"1374517800000","y":"1"},{"x":"1374604200000","y":"2"},{"x":"1374431400000","y":"0"},{"x":"1375122600000","y":"0"},{"x":"1375209000000","y":"0"}]}];`

As per the data, for `185271` there are two data one is 1 on 23-07-2013 and another is 2 on 24-07-2013. But if you see the attached image, there is a problem with date which is showing in x-axis. Even 24-07-2013 is not present in the x-axis. Even you can see there is a repeat of first date.
Please let me know where is the issue and what I have modify.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can have  a look

Comment: I am not able to run in jsfiddle, though I update the code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/srimanta/saXV5/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`X`** TimeStamp is a string it must be an Integer, hence the reason for the NaN been shown on the Tooltip, remove the double quotes.

Comment: I am getting another issue,If there are very less data then x-axis(date) is diving with multiple same date. e.g. I have only 2 dates 23-07-2013 and 24-07-2013 then I got 4 23-07-2013 columns in x-axis. I need only one 23-07-2013 in x-axis. Is it possible?

Comment: Take another look into the data you are passing, make sure you are not repeating any dates.